# Use of the 'compileOnly' scope in Android projects?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 2.12 (or newer) with an appropriate version of the Android Gradle plugin in my project. Gradle 2.12 introduced the `compileOnly` configuration, so why do I get an error when I try to use it?

> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple use `provided` instead of `compileOnly`

See https://github.com/google/auto/issues/324#issuecomment-212333044

Comment: That requires an additional "apt-plugin" according to the link that you provided.

Comment: So whats the problem adding a new plugin, If its required? compileOnly its a feature exclusive to Java plugin and the Android plugin hasn't the same features.

Comment: I haven't. But I expect the android Gradle plugin to support Gradle syntax. That's the issue here. Why it's not working and when to expect it to work

Comment: We are discussing your doubt, not expectations. You have to work accordingly with the features provided by the tool that you are using, right?

Comment: I argue that this gradle keyword is implicit in the Android Gradle plugin or that it is documented as a limitation. I accepted an answer that explains why it doesn't work. I still hope/expect this feature in a future version of the plugin, not having to add an additional one

Comment: I don't know in which version this has changed but, with android gradle plugin 2.3.2 I am able to use "provided" keyword without "apt". While @stkent's answer is very informative, this answer solves the problem and should be the accepted answer. Source : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#library_dependency_configurations

Comment: Based on the new facts provided by @wrecker I decided to accept this answer

Comment: Note that `provided` has been renamed "back" to `compileOnly` as of version 3.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin!

Answer (score 12):

Note the following sentence from the Gradle 2.12 release notes regarding the new [`compileOnly` configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin) (my emphasis):

> You can now declare dependencies to be used only at compile time **in conjunction with the Java plugin**.

So the Java Gradle plugin is a component we need to consider when answering this question. We can find the `compileOnly` configuration declared in the Java Gradle plugin [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/REL_2.14.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L59) for new enough versions.

However, **the Android Gradle plugins do not direct extend the Java Gradle plugin**. In fact, I believe the Android plugins represent a sort of 'frankenplugin', with some functionality *borrowed* but not *inherited* from the Java plugin. The following chunks of source code support this idea.

From [the base Android plugin class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy#199):

```
project.apply plugin: JavaBasePlugin
```

The Android Gradle plugins therefore incorporate functionality from the [*base* Java Gradle plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/REL_2.14.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin.java), *not* from the [*full* Java Gradle plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/REL_2.14.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java). Moreover, there is [an explicit check](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy#273) that the full Java Gradle plugin is not applied alongside an Android Gradle plugin:

```java
// get current plugins and look for the default Java plugin.
if (project.plugins.hasPlugin(JavaPlugin.class)) {
    throw new BadPluginException(
            "The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.")
}
```

Based on this information, my guess is that `compileOnly` has just not been manually ported from the Java Gradle plugin to the Android Gradle plugin yet. It probably won't appear before we get an Android Gradle plugin with minimum Gradle version set at 2.12 or higher.

Comment: News: the Android Gradle Plugin 2.1.3 requires Gradle 2.14.1. Could anyone confirm that this version supports the feature?

Comment: As of 2.2.2 it still doesn't